# Acumatica report authoring and single sign-on

Tags: oauth-2.0, acumatica

Our users authenticate to Acumatica using OAuth2-based SSO with Google as the identity provider. They do not have passwords to access the system (we generate very long, strong passwords which are discarded as soon as SSO is set up).

I don't want to go into all the reasons why SSO is important to us. It's critical, and I'll leave it at that. SSO was a policy and business requirement for us to select Acumatica.

The Report Designer doesn't seem to support OAuth2.

Is there a way we can give users the ability to download the RPX files via the browser, edit them outside the browser, and then upload the changes via the browser, using only SSO credentials?

Also, where can I get the source code to Report Designer? I'd love to see if I can add OAuth2 support myself.

Comment: Is this question about programming?

Comment: Yes it is related to programming and can't be solved by configuration. It's specific to Acumatica ERP platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of report in Acumatica:

1. [Standard Reports](https://www.acumatica.com/cloud-erp-software/reporting-dashboards-and-data-analysis/standard-reports-in-acumatica-erp/)
2. [Analytical Reports](https://www.acumatica.com/cloud-erp-software/reporting-dashboards-and-data-analysis/designing-custom-reports-in-acumatica-erp/)

The links above describe how you can customize these reports using Acumatica Cloud ERP.

You can notice that standard reports have the following limited customization possibility using Cloud ERP:

> You can adjust the report settings to meet your specific informational
>   needs. For example, you can specify sorting and filtering options and
>   select the data by using report-specific settings—such as financial
>   period, ledger, and account. You can configure additional processing
>   settings for each report.

Analytical reports have more customization possibilities through Cloud ERP:

> The Analytical Report Manager is a web-based tool for creating and
>   modifying analytical reports. Users can design and run custom
>   analytical reports using advanced data selection criteria, data
>   calculation rules, and customizable report layout design features. By
>   using the Analytical Report Manager, you can: Create the layout and
>   structure of reports based on your business requirements. Define data
>   selection criteria for the report with a high level of granularity.
>   For example, data sources can include a range of accounts,
>   subaccounts, and financial periods. Use advanced formulas to calculate
>   values based on the information extracted from the data source. Create
>   consolidated reports based on the data from multiple data sources or
>   other analytical reports. Localize data used by a report if
>   multilingual support of user input is enabled.

Acumatica marketing material shouldn't refer to the standard report editor (Windows Form Desktop Application) as part of the Cloud ERP product. The reason for this is quite simple, a Windows Desktop application is not a cloud product, it can't be accessed with a browser and is not supported on unix/apple OS.

Analytical reports designer support SSO OAuth since the designer is running on the Cloud ERP product.

Standard reports designer doesn't support OAuth. You could fill a feature request for it though. Our marketing material should not refer to standard report customization as part of the Cloud ERP product because the designer requirements are different.

We strive to make every feature available on Cloud ERP platform. At the moment these are the features not available on Cloud ERP to my knowledge:

- Standard Report Editor
- DeviceHub, this is a Windows program that acts    like a device
  spooler so you can access windows desktop hardware like    printer
  and scales from the Cloud ERP.
- Login page customization, this    can't be achieved through
  Customization Project Editor, you have to    change files manually on
  the server.

---

From now on, I'll focus on the Standard Report Designer, the Windows Desktop Application.

The designer uses the Web Service API to communicate with Acumatica Database.
Besides loading and saving RPX files the report designer also uses the Web Service API for features in 'File->Build Schema' dialog like 'Load Schema'. If your user are not using the 'Build Schema' features then having only the RPX file locally should be enough to allow them to modify the report using the designer.

Code for loading and saving RPX files is located in PX.Reports.Design.ReportUtils class which is part of PX.Reports.Design.dll assembly. It's using the SOAP API which to my knowledge is not the preferred API to use OAuth, the REST Contract API is recommended for OAuth enabled Web Services. Refactoring the PX.Reports.Design.dll assembly to use REST Contract API instead of SOAP API isn't trivial.

That said I believe it's possible to load and save RPX files using the Rest API and you could write a wrapper for the report designer to handle that task as long as you forgo 'Build Schema' feature. I'll touch on that at the end of my answer.

You can find the documentation for [using OAuth with Rest API here](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Main.aspx?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ff780860-09c2-46c9-bdd7-c6c3b1fc442c)

---

There are two ways you can use Acumatica Web Service, attended or unattended.
Attended use requires a user to enter his credentials in some form of UI before using the web service. The report designer uses this form of authentication.

The alternative for unattended use is to configure and save the authentication credentials before using the web service. That way an automated program can use web service API without requiring a user sitting in front of the computer.

Unattended use typically doesn't involve OAuth because you can't have a user dedicated to the task of authenticating. For example, if you integrate Acumatica with an ecommerce provider, requiring him to use OAuth authorization to push the orders to Acumatica is problematic because that process usually doesn't involve a UI where a user sitting at the computer provide authorization.

You could technically create a OAuth access token that never (rarely) expires for this task but it circumvents the purpose of OAuth which is having temporary access tokens to mitigate man in the middle attacks. Certifications that mandates use of OAuth typically forbid use of tokens that never expire. That's why requesting OAuth for automated process can raise eyebrows and lead programmers to question your security policies.

---

Now let's get to possible solutions for your problem. You'll have to assess  whether your security policies allows use of unattended web service without OAuth authorization. If that's the case then your job will be much easier. If not then you'll likely run into similar problems later on if dealing with third party web service integration for Acumatica is required.

In order to write a wrapper over the report designer you'll have to write a windows desktop application and have the '.RPS' file type associated with your wrapper instead of being associated with Acumatica report designer.

When a user clicks the EDIT REPORT button on the website, a '.RPS' text file is generated in memory on the server and the user browser is redirected to that file in order to download it locally. When the user clicks on the RPS file, windows launches the associated program (Acumatica report designer) and passes the RPS file path by command line parameter. The report designer then presents the authorization dialog where user can enter his credentials and the report RPX file is downloaded by the Web Service API.

Example of the content of an RPS file:

```
ServiceUrl|http://localhost/AcumaticaInstance/
ReportName|gl633000.rpx
User|admin
```

The idea is to have your wrapper parse this RPS file, download the associated RPX file using the Web Service API that comply with your security policy and then launch Acumatica report designer for this RPX file using command line parameter:

```
"c:\...\ReportDesigner.exe" "c:\...'gl633000.rpx"
```

When you launch the report designer you want to halt your main thread until the user closes the report designer. Framework methods that do this are typically named 'wait for exit'. Before closing the report designer the user would save the RPX file. After the designer is closed your main thread will resume and you can then re-upload that RPX file to Acumatica database using Web Service API.

The easy way would be to create a report designer user to use Web Service API in unattended mode. You could store those credentials locally (in encrypted form) wherever you see fit and never expose them in UI. When making Web Service call you decrypt those credentials on the fly. In such a scenario the asset to protect is the decryption key.

If use of attended web service is required for OAuth support you will need to implement a UI to get those credentials. If you have to use Google login page for entering the credentials you would have to include an embedded browser in your wrapper for that purpose.

As a remainder, note that this solution will enable you to modify the report definition in the RPX file but will not enable you to use report designer features that require web service API like 'Build Schema'.

Comment: @hb-acumatica Can we integrate custom identity server like IdentityServer4 as SSO provider? Acumatica supports Google and Microsoft SSO integration but does it support for other custom Identity provider integration?

Comment: Technically you can, there's a plugin system for that and I developed integration with OneLogin using it which Acumatica now offers. However it is not easy and documentation is lacking.